# Generate XLSX with PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have gone through other questions of this type but most of it were by using external libraries. I am able to generate excel with the extension .xls with no library at all. However I am aware that changing xls to xlsx in PHP does not mean we can generate .xlsx file. So is there a simpler way to do this without referring to any library?

```
        $output .= '</table>';
        $fileName = "ExcelFile".date('Y_m_d').".xls";
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
        echo $output;
```

The reason why I want to do this is because when I generate .xls, the file opens and shows me a message : "The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?". Is there a way to avoid this message with .xls? Since as per my research, it does not appear in .xslx file.

EDIT: As per the comment, it seems the culprit could be SQL table. Here is the complete code.

```
...
...
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $output .= '
        <table class = "table" bordered = "1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>       
        ';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
                <th>'.$row["ID"].'</th>
                <th>'.$row["Name"].'</th>
            </tr>
            ';
        }

        $output .= '</table>';
        $fileName = "ExcelFile".date('Y_m_d').".xls";
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
        echo $output;
    }
```

Comment: These are two completely different formats. Is there any good reason **not** to use a library?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hi Nico. I have just updated my question

Comment: I suspect the error message comes from what you are putting _into_ `$output`. It's a while since I looked, but as far as I remember `.xls` files are not plain text, so something that ends in `</table>` isn't likely to be a valid xls-formatted file, any more than naming something `.jpg` makes it a valid jpg image. You're more likely to be able to produce `.xlsx` files the way you are doing, because they're xml format, aren't they?.

Comment: All I am doing is adding the values from SQL table to this. So what is the alternative for this?

Comment: Use a library to create the file in the correct format, or use a different format. Call it CSV perhaps and let Excel import it? Or is there some other issue in the file contents causing the problem?

Comment: The alternative is to use a proper library. What's the reason to not do so? If you want to create a genuine XLSX file, then you need to either a) implement the entire openXML specification in PHP yourself, or b) use a (free) library where someone has already done all those weeks of hard work for you and probably also fixed all the bugs that arise from that complex process.

Comment: P.S. what you're generating right now isn't a real XLS file either, it's just a HTML document with the wrong file extension. Excel happens to be able to read (some) HTML and display it, after a fashion, but it's a long, long way from actually being a binary XLS file.

Comment: @ADyson The reason I did not want to use another library was because I thought we can generate an excel sheet without one. Now when I include the library, I must change the code as well.

Comment: "I thought we can generate an excel sheet without one" ...well you could, if you replaced all the functionality of the library with the same functionality, except written by you instead of someone else. XLS and XLSX are both complex file formats. Hence why people write large code libraries to deal with them. Sure you could just create a simple CSV file, or even a HTML file which (if done correctly) Excel would know how to read, but that isn't the same thing as creating a genuine full-featured Excel file.

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If you just want a super-simple table, then CSV is likely to be more reliable than HTML (in terms of Excel being able to open it). If you need colours, complex tables, styles, formulas etc then you need the full Excel format. I wouldn't really say HTML was ever a good choice particularly. And... _"when I include the library, I must change the code as well"_ ... well yes, but then again either way, if your code's not working, you're going have to change it, aren't you!

Comment: Okay got it then. I will include a library and rewrite the code. That way it will be in proper format.

Comment: P.S. if you want to use CSV for simplicity, then you don't need another library - the functionality is already built into PHP via [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and related functions.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will go with a library since I feel the functionality of more operations for Excel could be done via PHP itself.

Comment: Just for a quick fix, is there a way to avoid the message "The file could be corrupted or unsafe...." with my code pasted above? @ADyson

Comment: At a guess you maybe need to have all the components of a valid HTML document in there, including the html, head, body tags etc, not just the table. But I haven't tried to fake a HTML document as an Excel document, so I can't be sure. Maybe somewhere online there's an example that works.